# At what resolution use a high quality image

Tags: html, image, css, photoshop, screen-resolution

With high-resolution display e.g. Apple retina it is good to use high-resolution images for a good visual user experience.

You can use e.g. CSS3 or HTML

CSS:

```
#myimage {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url(lo-res.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

@media
    screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
        #myimage {
            background-image: url(hi-res.jpg);
        }
   }
```

HTML:

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="head.jpg, head-2x.jpg 2x">
  <source media="(min-width: 450px)" srcset="head-small.jpg, head-small-2x.jpg 2x">
  <img src="head-fb.jpg" srcset="head-fb-2x.jpg 2x" alt="a head carved out of wood">
</picture>
```

But in case of the HTML code above, when would you switch to a high-resolution image? At what screen width?

Comment: I would go mobile first and *always* serve a HDPI image if the browser needs it and can handle it, hence the `2x`. See https://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/high-dpi/ for some details. You could also make use of `sizes`, see https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-responsive-images-with-srcset/